# php preg_match to validate twitter username

Tags: php, regex, twitter

What is the pattern to validate a twitter username using `preg_match`?

Comment: Do you mean Twitter username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter allows you to use letters, numbers, and '_', so

`preg_match("/[a-z0-9_]+/i", username)`

for a case-insensitive search with at least one character.

Answer (score 3):

I think greg forgot the "@" that indicates the beginning of a twitter handler:

```
preg_match("/\@[a-z0-9_]+/i", $username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet:

```
preg_match('/^\@[\w]+$/', $value);
```